# Heat map with time for LineString s

Tags: python, heatmap, geopandas, folium, shapely

I have data on the traffic in some roads. I would like to plot it as a "heatmap", showing how busy different roads are over time with a map in the background (e.g. an OpenStreetMap). If possible in Python.

Meaning, that one would see a map with the linestrings (streets) printed on it, and as time varies the color of the linestrings varies, representing the respective "weight".

Possibly somebody has an idea, how one could plot this`?

Please find below a sample data, which depicts some streets ( 3) over time (2 timesteps).

| Index | name | date | weight | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | street_a | 2020-09-01 00:00:00 | 0.350568 | LINESTRING (52.5336851 13.4097258, 52.5336223 13.409661, 52.533469 13.4095067, 52.5333874 13.4094228) |
| 2 | street_b | 2020-09-01 00:00:00 | 0.437344 | LINESTRING (52.5348784 13.4030152, 52.5347517 13.4030678, 52.5345239 13.4031625, 52.534101 13.4033438, 52.5340545 13.4033634, 52.5339875 13.4033926, 52.533968 13.4033984) |
| 3 | steet_c | 2020-09-01 00:00:00 | 0.668961 | LINESTRING (52.5348784 13.4030152, 52.5348746 13.4029029, 52.534889 13.4027999, 52.5349209 13.4027148) |
| 4 | street_a | 2020-09-01 01:00:00 | 0.818416 | LINESTRING (52.5336851 13.4097258, 52.5336223 13.409661, 52.533469 13.4095067, 52.5333874 13.4094228) |
| 5 | street_b | 2020-09-01 01:00:00 | 0.174643 | LINESTRING (52.5348784 13.4030152, 52.5347517 13.4030678, 52.5345239 13.4031625, 52.534101 13.4033438, 52.5340545 13.4033634, 52.5339875 13.4033926, 52.533968 13.4033984) |
| 6 | street_c | 2020-09-01 01:00:00 | 0.028408 | LINESTRING (52.5348784 13.4030152, 52.5348746 13.4029029, 52.534889 13.4027999, 52.5349209 13.4027148) |

I have seen that something like this is possible with folium and the [HeatMapWithTIme](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/latest/reference.html#module-folium.plugins), However, they only accept points and not LineStrings. Similarly I have seen that one can plot LineStrings with [.explore()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70386381/plotting-linestrings-with-a-colomap-geopandas-and-folium) However, I could not find a way to add a time dimension to this.